# How to kill a turtle for not having a link?

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics, die

I have a network that creates undirected links between two breeds of turtles. Sometimes one end of a link (between two turtles) dies and my doubt is: how to kill the remaining end based on the condition: if a turtle don't have a link `[die]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ask turtles with [ not any? my-links ] [ die ]`